# running a VMWare image in the cloud

Tags: macos, azure, amazon-web-services, vmware

I'm running Windows 8.1 in a VMWare Fusion virtual machine hosted on OSX. I want to know if there's anyway to take the VMWare file and run it on Windows Azure (or AWS) so I can run my development environment in the cloud.

Comment: http://messor.com/migrating-a-vmware-vm-to-azure/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, AWS's import/export feature (and actually AWS in general) does not support Windows 8.1 (actually any Windows desktop version is not supported on AWS).
The same goes for Google Compute Engine which supports just Windows 2008r2.

I believe it should be doable on Azure, by employing some conversions - first convert from VMware's image format (VMDK) to MS HyperV's (VHD), prepare the image (sysprep, replace devices and drivers, etc.) and then upload to Azure - this is **not** a simple process, but googling for **azure upload vmdk** .

An alternative would be to start with a blank Windows 8.1 VM on Azure, and just install whatever software you need on it from scratch.

Another alternative (probably the simplest if you have a lot of software already installed on your Windows 8.1 VM) would be to use a service like Ravello Systems (http://www.ravellosystems.com) which lets you easily upload any VMware VM (including Windows 8.1) and run it on multiple cloud providers (e.g. AWS, GCE, ...)

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a VM import/export feature:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

Comment: yep, but list of supported OSs is very limited, so Ravello suites better for importing VMs